# Scalable & Dragable Label on top of Image

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to create Scalable & Dragable Label on top of Image, I should be able to type inside label and also should be able to add more Labels by clicking "+ ADD LABEL" button.

[image: Scalable & Dragable Label on top of ImageDD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/125/

This may not be perfect but you can work upon it. It's just a base from where you can start.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        handler();
        $('a').click(function () {
            var div = $('<div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 1</div>');
            $('body').append(div);
            handler();
            return false;
        });
    });

    function handler(){
    $('.label').draggable({
            refreshPositions: true,
        })
            .click(function () {
            $(this).draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
        }).dblclick(function () {
            $(this).draggable({
                disabled: true
            });
        }).resizable({
            handles: "all",
        });   
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="">+Add</a>        
    <img src="http://www.freedomscientific.com/images/resources/human_eye.jpg" class="img" />
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 1</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 2</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 3</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 4</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 5</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 6</div>
    <div class="label" contenteditable="true">Part 7</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .label {
        border:1px solid red;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    a {
        position:fixed;
        top:10px;
        right:10px;
        padding:5px;
        background-color:green;
        color:white
    }
```

For square resizable handles, you can customize your css accordingly